# show loader div on jquery dialog instead of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dialog

my jquery dialog code has some input fields and a submit

onSubmit i show the loader div

the code snippet is

```
$("#loading").show();
$("#loading-overlay").css("position", "fixed");
$("#loading-overlay").css("display", "block");
```

the html is

```
<div id="loading-overlay">
</div>
<div id="loading">
    <span>Loading...</span>
</div>
```

here the id for that div applies style to that div using some css,
i am using a template for applying that style,

i want to show the actual scenario in images

This is my JQUERY DIALOG
[image: This is my JQUERY DIALOG]

This is my JQUERY DIALOG after submit
[image: This is my JQUERY DIALOG after submit]

the loader is working but it should be shown on the dialog not under the dialog
this is my scenario.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to increase ```z-index``` of the loader higher than the dialog's ```z-index```.

Comment: z-index alone wouldnt do it, but would you be able to set css to absolute and change the left margin?  This isnt the exact way to do it but it should be a simple band aid.

Comment: ^ That won't remove the modal-like backdrop covering the loader.

Comment: to show loader div i moved dialog but actual dialog will be positioned at center

Answer (score 0):

Use css-position and **z-index for loader**.

You can achieve this by following:

```
#loading{width:100%;height:100%;
    background-image:url('loader.gif');
    background-position:centre;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999}
```

Comment: Mind if you update your answer with proper markdown?

Comment: Does it helped or need complete css?

Comment: i tried to apply `$("#loading-overlay").css("z-index", "999");` but its not workin

Comment: Have you used width:100% and Height:100%; and position:fixed;?

Comment: Try to increase z-index more lets say: z-index:999999999

Comment: the height and width will be already given to 100% and i gave the code i tried above in which it contains position fixed 
`$("#loading").show();

$("#loading-overlay").css("position", "fixed");
$("#loading-overlay").css("display", "block");`  is written above

Comment: Ok. Do exactly this <br> Make one div and give width and height 100, position fixed<br>inside that div, make another div of required size to show loader image with margin lets say 100 auto<br>And do remember z-index to be highest for main div<br>Also give z-index to jQuery Dialog less than loader

Comment: thanks for your clue bro :) i found [zIndex()](http://api.jqueryui.com/zIndex/)  to find parent zindex and increment one for that and assign to loader div

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to your CSS. where `.loader` is the class-name of your loader element.

```
.loader {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks j_freyre and priti but its not working for me

Comment: May be some other Class(s) overriding your Current style.
Try giving inline style to your Loader-div. style="z-index: 9999 !important;"

Comment: thanks #priti , i found the solution and i updated it as answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help you, add this with your loader class/id, whatever

```
 {
  z-index:99999 !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var zi = $("#parent_dialog_name").zIndex();
var lzi;
if (zi > 0) { lzi = zi + 1; }
else { lzi = 0; }
$("#loading").show();
$("#loading-overlay").css("position", "fixed");
$("#loading-overlay").css("display", "block");
$("#loading-overlay").zIndex(lzi);
$("#loading").zIndex(lzi + 1);
```

i have done this to solve my problem